# How to get a value/variable from a table in corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What if I wanted to check one variable or get one value from a table I created in corona SDK? I know you use index numbers in C++, but when I tried that it did not work.

in main.lua:

```
local table = {}
table.first = "string"
table.second = 25
table.third = "I want to get this one"

loadsave.saveTable(table,"table.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
```

in another.lua

```
local getTable = loadsave.loadTable("table.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
--here I would like to get the third value from the table and print it
```

Comment: `getTable.third`

Comment: `local table()` is not valid Lua. Reading the excellent book [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/) would help to answer extremely basic questions like this. 1st edition is available for free [online](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
local table = {}
table.third = "I want to get this one"

print( table.third )
===============================
output: "I want to get this one"
```

[Also check this link for more about tables in lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)